# Search in array child firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I retrieve all the documents who match a child in a data structure like this:

```
{
  [
    id: {
      name: "name",
      products: {
        items: [
          productName: "this is the product Name"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The parameter i try to compare is the one inside **products.items[0].productName.**

this is how i tried but it does not retrieve anything:

```js
try{
        var data = [];
        const byName = await dbRef.where('producto.items[0].producto', '==', req.params.nombre).get();
        console.log(byName);
        if (byName.empty) {
            console.log('No matching documents.');
            res.send('No matching documents.');
            return;
          }  
          
          byName.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            data.push(doc.data());
          });

          res.send(data);
    }catch(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
```

Comment: I can't tell what your query is trying to do.  It doesn't seem to match the document structure you provided.  In any case, Firestore just doesn't support using indexes in arrays in a query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search across all items in the `items` array for one that matches the value you have, you can use the [`array-contains` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership):

```
dbRef.where('producto.items', 'array-contains', { producto: req.params.nombre})
```

But note that this only works if the array **only** contains the `producto` field in each item. The reason is that `array-contains` (and other array-level operators) work on complete items only.

So if the items in `producto.items` have multiple subfields, and you want to match on one/some of them, you can't use `array-contains`. In that case, you're options are:

- Store the items names in a separate/additional array field `product-names` and then query on that with `array-contains`.
- Store the array items in a subcollection and query that.
- Use a map instead of an array to store these values. This will generate many extra indexes though, which both adds to your storage cost, and may get you to the [limit on the number of indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes).